# Using awk to get unique values from column 1, and sum corresponding values in column 2?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, grep

I have a CSV file in the following format, I was told at work this is a "map reduce problem"
{
Server1,33.23
Server2,43.46
Server3,64.34
Server4,56.89
Server2,33.24
Server1,21.40
Server2,33.46
}

It is several thousand lines long and there are around 80 server names which appear several times each in column 1, and column 2 is Mbs. For every occurance of a server name in column 1 add the corresponding value in column 2. So I am left with a new table with no duplicates in column 1 and just the total sum of Mbs from column 2.

So in case I was unclear - for every occurance of any unique value in column 1, add the corresponding values in column 2. And in the end I'd have.

Server1,TotalMbs
Server2,TotalMbs
Server3,TotalMbs

I know this can be done with awk but I can't figure out how, I think passing in the value in column 1 and then increment a count in column 2 and keep doing it line by line. It's quite tricky??? My long and inelegant solution will be to create a temp file for each server in a loop then just total column 2 for each file then rm the files at the end but I know it can be done in a one liner with awk.

Comment: Please post sample input and sample output too in code tags in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `awk` script might help you,

```
$ awk -F'[ |,]'  '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~ "Server")a[$i]+=$(i+1)}END{for(i in a)printf "%s,%s ",i,a[i];printf "\n"}' input_file
Server3,64.34 Server4,56.89 Server1,54.63 Server2,110.16
```

If ordered output is required, add `BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"}` to the BIGIN block,

```
$ awk -F'[ |,]'  'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~ "Server")a[$i]+=$(i+1)}END{for(i in a)printf "%s,%s ",i,a[i];printf "\n"}' input_file
Server1,54.63 Server2,110.16 Server3,64.34 Server4,56.89
```

The oneliner could also be written like this:

```
awk -F'[ |,]' '{
    if($i ~ "Server")
      a[$i]+=$(i+1)
} END{
  for(i in a)
    printf "%s,%s ",i,a[i];
  printf "\n"
}' input_file
```

Brief explanation,

1. Set " " and "," as the delimeters
2. Scan each line, find "Server" in each column, and store the value of the next column into the corresponding key of `a`, i.e. `a[$i]=$(i+1)`, if we found.

Comment: This worked a charm - thanks so much ! My friend did it with a 40 line python script but I knew it was possible with awk!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F',' '{ 
             servers[$1] += $;
           } 
           END {
             for (server in servers) { 
               printf("%s %f\n", server, servers[server]); 
             }
           }'
```

If you want to filter on specific servers, you can add a '//' match to the first block, to make it only execute on lines that match the condition.